# Lifting diffeomorphisms in $S^2$ by the Hopf fibration.

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, geometric-topology

Can you lift a diffeomorphism $f$ on $S^2$ to a diffeomorphism $F$ on $S^3$ preserving the Hopf fibration structure $\pi:S^3\mapsto S^2$, i.e. such that $\pi\circ F=f\circ \pi$.

I think that if we take a rotation on $S^2$ around the $z$-axis by angle $\theta$ then this can indeed be lifted to a diffeomorphism in $F:S^3\mapsto S^3$ given by
$$F(z_1,z_2)=(e^{i\theta}z_1,z_2)$$

But I don't know if this holds for general diffeomorphisms on $S^2$, or at least diffeomorphisms isotopic to the identity, this last case would be enough for me.

So if anyone knows an answer to this I would be deeply grateful.

Comment: What happens if you try pulling back the fibration $\pi$ along $f$?

Comment: @JHF I guess you are trying to suggest that just pulling back the fibration will give you indeed the definition of the map $F:S^2\mapsto S^2$  ??? Is that correct?

Comment: Well, $F$ is a map $S^3 \to S^3$, not between $S^2$, and I suppose you still have to check that it's a diffeomorphism and that the pullback fibration is isomorphic to the Hopf fibration, but I don't think this is difficult.

Comment: Why $F(z_1, z_2)$ if its domain is $\Bbb S^3$?

Comment: @Ilya $F(z_1,z_2)$ makes sense by using the induced coordinates of $S^3\subset \mathbb{C}^2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Hopf fibration is a fibre bundle with fibre $S^1$. If you have a diffeomorphism $f:M\to N$ and a fibre bundle $\pi_N:P\to N$, you can obtain the pullback bundle $\pi_M:f^*P\to M$. In particular, the pullback bundle is diffeomorphic to the original $P$, because $f$ was a diffeomorphism, so $F:f^*P\to P$, and you have $\pi_N\circ F=f\circ\pi_M$. This is also what is suggested in the comments

Comment: This answer is incomplete. Although the map $F : f^*P \to P$ is a fiber preserving diffeomorphism which projects to the diffeomorphism $f : S^2 \to S^2$, that's not what is asked for. What is asked for is a fiber preserving diffeomorphism $F : P \to P$ which projects to the diffeomorphism $f$.  The comment of @JHF hints at how to do this.

Comment: You are right. I was writing a more elaborate answer but then realised it had already been answered in the comments, so I just referred to that to take the question off the "unanswered" list. I hope that is acceptable.